# Should I include a paper published in a non English language in my CV?

Tags: publications, cv

I have written a paper in my own language. Is it right to write it in my CV as a published paper?

Comment: Has the paper been published in a workshop/conference/journal? Then yes, I'd include it in your CV

Comment: yes, it has published and I have had a 20 min talk about it.

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari please, include these details in the question.

Comment: Of course it is.  Especially if it's a paper you are proud of.  Especially if you hope someone might one day be interested in translating it.  And *especially* if you want someone to see it.

Comment: It depends. Where are you going to send your CV to? For what purpose? You don't have one CV. You tailor it to the application, just like a cover letter. Without it, this question seems to be unanswerable to me.

Comment: @Bernhard I can't imagine an academic CV that didn't include publications. So, as long as this question is about a CV to be used to apply for academic jobs, no further details are needed for this question.

Comment: @David I am not sure if you should include all papers, rather than just a few key paper. In any case you are now just assuming this is for an academic application. If it is, then it would make a difference depending on the kind of position.

Comment: @Bernhard I'm assuming it's for an academic position because, if it's not, then the question is completely off-topic, here. I've never seen an academic CV that didn't list all the person's publications and I can't imagine an academic position where you wouldn't want to list them all. Academic CVs are very different to ordinary business CVs; it sounds like you're not very familiar with them.

Comment: @DavidRicherby So for a professor with 200+ papers, you would just list them all on the CV?

Comment: @Bernhard Yes. (Though somebody with that many papers is probably so well known that it doesn't much matter what they put on their CV.)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you have published a paper, you should include it in your CV.  It does not matter what language the paper is in.

For the aid of people who do not speak the language, however, you may wish to include a translation of the paper title as a note, e.g.,:

> J. Caesar, *Commentarii de Bello Gallico [Commentaries on the Gallic war]*, Caesar House Press, 49 BC, (in Latin)

Comment: -1E-20 for the translation (should read "Commentaries on the Gallic war")

Comment: @Bort Thank you, fixed it: it's been a long time since Latin class.

Comment: I would go with: J. Caesar, _Commentarii de Bello Gallacio_ [_Commentaries on the Gallic war_], Caesar House Press, 49 BC, (in Latin). It's good to put the English title earlier, and to mention the language of the works.

Comment: @yo' That's a nice way to format it: I'll incorporate it into the answer.

Comment: Behold, my beautiful [bikeshed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality)!

Comment: Ah, hadn't heard the term "bikeshed(ding)" till just now.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you should. It is well known that the best journals are in English but there are others that can be not bad and they are not necessarily written in English. 
In South America there are a couple of journals that are not on the top ten, but maybe on the second quartile and they have articles both in English and Spanish. 
Also, you worked on that paper so this may not add a lot to your cv but it is better than nothing! :)

Comment: "The best journals are in English" — that's going to be highly field specific. The best journals in my field are definitively *not* in English.

Comment: It is not true that all the top journals (e.g., in mathematics) are in English, though many are.

Comment: Now, this is just too subjective and too bold. Also, this does not answer the question.

Comment: You are right, this is too field specific. I was,of course, thinking about my field, where all the top journals are in English, but it may not be the case for other disciplines. However, even in my field I would include a publication written in a different language.

Answer (score 1):

You should, if you consider this work worth mentioning. Interestingly, this could trigger the curiosity of the reader, with if often nice when people receive hundredth of resumes.

If  you "have had a 20 min talk about it", I guess it could be at a conference. It could be tagged for instance with "National conference" (if it was indeed national), and the title translated as suggested by  @jakebeal. 
However, international conferences exist in other languages than English, so it could be an international conference, and you should mention that, to help the reader evaluate the context of publication.